# How can I set a value for each element of a Matrix of N dimension?

Tags: c#, loops, recursion, multidimensional-array, mapping

So, this is kinda long and complicated but hear me out, recently I´ve been studing about Matrices and setting coordinates to map the movement of NPCs in videogames and that got me into multidimensional matrices for no reason. So I created a 3D matrix and gave a value for each element depending on the order it was in the matrix, like this: (PS. this was created on Unity)

```
public class MatrixUnit
{
    public int length;
    public int width;
    public int height;
    public void Maping(int x, int y, int z)
    {
        this.length = x;
        this.width = y;
        this.height = z;
    }


}

public class MatrixManager : MonoBehavior
{
    public MatrixUnit[,,] Matrix = new MatrixUnit[12, 14, 2];
       public void CreateMatrix()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < Matrix.GetLength(0); i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < Matrix.GetLength(1); j++)
            {
                for (int k = 0; k < Matrix.GetLength(2); k++)
                {
                    Matrix[i, j, k] = new MatrixUnit();
                }
            }
        }
    }
       public void MatrixMapStart()
        {
           for (int i = 0; i < Matrix.GetLength(0); i++)
           {
               for (int j = 0; j < Matrix.GetLength(1); j++)
               {
                  for (int k = 0; k < Matrix.GetLength(2); k++)
                   {
                    if (Matrix[i, j, k] != null)
                    {
                        Matrix[i, j, k].Maping(i, j, k);
                        Debug.Log("Element " + ((i * Matrix.GetLength(1) * Matrix.GetLength(2)) + (j * Matrix.GetLength(2)) + k + 1) + " is in the position " + Matrix[i, j, k].length + ", " + Matrix[i, j, k].width + ", " + Matrix[i, j, k].height);
                    }
                   }
               }
           }
       }
   void Start()
   {
       CreateMatrix();
       MatrixMapStart();
   }
}
```

I specially enjoy the "((i * Matrix.GetLength(1) * Matrix.GetLength(2)) + (j * Matrix.GetLength(2)) + k + 1)" because it works in any matrix with any size, it could be a 10x10x10 matrix or a 13x47x4 matrix and it would still work nicelly (tested!)

With this I reached the obvious conclusion that if I wanted to map a 4D matrix I would need 4 "for" loops and that got me wondering if there was a way to map a method that could map a matrix of N dimensions by only giving it the imput of the matrix itself, like "public void MapingMethod(MatrixWithNDimensions)".
So I asked my professor in college to help me out and he got quite curious himself and he told me to study recursion, I got how it works but so far I haven't been able to quite crack this one yet. By the way, english isn't my first language so sorry for any mispelling.

So far I have been trying but I haven't really gotten anywhere. I'm firstly trying to understand what the logic would be in a two dimensional matrix. I know that if I wanted to do it with for loops it would look a bit like this:

```
    public class Item()
    {
        public int value;
    }
        public Item[,] Matrix2D = new Item[5,12];
        public void CreateMatrix2D()
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < Matrix2D.GetLength(0); i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < Matrix2D.GetLength(1); j++)
                {
                    Matrix2D[i, j] = new Item();
                }
            }
        }
        public void Map()
        {
            for (int i = 0;i < Matrix2D.GetLength(0);i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0;j < Matrix2D.GetLength(1);j++)
                {
                    Matrix2D[i, j].value = ((i * Matrix2D.GetLength(0)) + j);
                }
            }
        }
```

(I know I don't need to create a class to make the Matrix but I want to practice it with classes so I can expand it in the future by not only giving them a numeric order but many other values as well)

My first Ideia was to somehow make a variable N that equals "MatrixN.GetLength(N), MatrixN.GetLength(N+1), MatrixN.GetLength(N+2), ... , MatrixN.GetLength(0)" so i could write the line Matrix[N].

I have no ideia if this is even possible since I'm quite new to C# and programming and I'm also probably bitting way more than I can chew, but I can't help it, this is really fun. If anyone can help that would be much apriciated!

Answer (score 0):

The pattern you want to implement looks like this:

- you loop on the current level
- if it's a leaf level, perform an action based on the results of `GetLength` multiplied with the corresponding index
- if it's not a leaf level, compute a further level

So, it could look like:

```
public int GetMyValue(Array matrix, int dimensionCount, valueSoFar = 0) {
    for (int i = 0; i < matrix.Length(); i++) {
        int prod = i;
        if (dimensionCount == 1) {
            return f(valueSoFar + prod + 1);
        } else {
            for (int j = 1; j < dimensionCount; j++) {
                prod *= matrix.GetLength(j);
            }
            return GetMyValue(matrix[i], dimensionCount - 1, valueSoFar + prod);
        }
    }
}
```

And you can call it like

```
GetMyValue(yourMatrix, 3);
```

Explanation:

- when you initially call your method, you pass your matrix (i.e. a 3D matrix you initially had) and when you call the method inside, you call `matrix[i]`, which is taking a sub-array as new reference-point to the sub-level of this recursive call-chain and therefore the second level will have 1 dimension less than the first one (i.e., a 3D matrix will lead to passing a 2D matrix recursively)
- if you first pass a 3D array, then on the second level you will have calls where each item is passed, having 2D arrays at each call at the second level and, at the third level you pass each item of each item, passing 1D arrays on the third level
- `dimensionCount` is the level of dimensions at the current depth and whenever the function calls itself, `dimensionCount - 1` is being passed
- `valueSoFar` is the value so far, so at the initial call you do not even have to pass it, because it defaults to 0
- at any level, leaf or not, you need to loop the current dimension
- we set `prod = i` initially so we know what the index of the current dimension is
- if `dimensionCount == 1`, that means that we are on a leaf node in the call graph and we can call `f` (a function you need to define) and pass `valueSoFar + prod + 1`, so this would be "whatever we've got on earlier dimensions + k + 1" from your example
- otherwise we need to loop the dimensions from 1 to the dimension limit and multiply `prod` with `matrix.GetLength(j)`, because when we speak of 2D arrays, we need to have `i * matrix.GetLength(1) * matrix.GetLength(2)`, as we can see, from 1 to the number of dimensions of your arrays. Now, if you have arrays of 2D, then `dimensionCount` is 3

  - once we get the right result for `prod`, we can call `GetMyValue` on a lower dimension
  - so we pass `matrix[i]`, that is, if `dimensionCount` was 3, then you pass each 2D arrays your 3D array has
  - we pass `dimensionCount - 1`, so `dimensionCount` will be one less on the next level, but unchanged on this level
  - we pass `valueSoFar + prod`, that is, we had a `valueSoFar` as a natural number (0 by default) so far and we add `prod` to the result and pass to the method, so the next level will have this sum as the input and the current level will have `valueSoFar` unchanged, so the next items will not be polluted in the loop

The code is untested, homework-1 is to test it and fix any errors I may have left inside of it and homework-2 is that, after you've made this recursive call work, convert the algorithm to iterative, that is, to use a stack and manage it instead of relying on the stack of your memory (which recursion essentially does).